# Azure AD B2C Custom SignIn Policy Displays SignUpSignIn

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom SignIn policy, because I need to fetch something from an application database (via REST API) during the sign in process.

So I have this user journey

```
<UserJourney Id="SignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.localaccountsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GetCustomDbObj" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GetCustomDbObj" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

You can see that in step #3, I have a reference to a custom technical profile that fetches some data from a custom REST API.

In the first step, I display (supposedly) the sign in page, it references `api.localaccountsignin`

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/default/signin.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/default/signin.cshtml</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="TemplateId">azureBlue</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
```

The problem is that when I use the policy, I see a page that resembles the signup+signin unified policy

[image]

Instead of just the sign in policy, which is what I desire.

I suspect that it has something to do with

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.localaccountsignin">
```

More specifically, `CombinedSignInAndSignUp`
But I don't know what to put instead. I tried using `ClaimsExchange` but it didn't work.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile. There are more you can customize like what you asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-eb63b508a075):

You can achieve this by setting SignUp to “False”.

```
<Item Key=”setting.showSignupLink”>False</Item>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Really hard to find documentation about this stuff...